# call function in swift file from objective-c file with completion handler (closure) syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures

I am having trouble calling a function in a swift file from an objective-c file where there is a closure in the swift function.

This is the Swift function

```
//In Utilities class

static func getString(query: NSString, completion: @escaping (_ response: NSString) -> Void) {

        completion("hello")
    }
```

This is how I try to call it in the objective-c class:

```
 [Utilities getString:@"hi there" completion:^(NSString* response) {
     NSLog(response);
    }];
```

I'm getting the error 'No known class method for selector 'getString:completion:'

What is wrong with above?

Note: I am able to call a simpler method without the closure/completion bloc.

```
in swift class
static func myTest () {
      print("function called")
    }
```

called from objective-c class with:

```
[Utilities myTest];
```

SO the problem seems to relate to the closure syntax.

Comment: And what the autocompletion says? Shouldn't this be maybe `getStringQuery:completion` maybe? Missing @object?

Comment: Damon, I looked at that question.  It is a different error.  Not the same.  Also the issue and solution to that question had to do with optionals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the class with

```
@objcMembers class Utilities:NSObject {
```

or the function

```
@objc class func getString(query: NSString, completion: @escaping (_ response: NSString) -> Void) {
```

---

```
[Utilities getStringWithQuery:@"hi there" completion:^(NSString* response) {
 NSLog(response);
}];
```

Comment: I am currently surrounding the class name as follows:   @objc class Utilities:NSObject {

Comment: the problem is in the function , so follow anyone of the above

Comment: I tried prefixing the function with @objc class instead of static and same error

Comment: Copied your code exactly but getting same error.  Did not know you substitute withQuery for (query)... translating between two languages.  Is that rule?

Comment: Ok. Got it to work. Did not know about With but that seems to have fixed it.